# Sampling From Four-Parameter Beta Distribution

Tags: sampling, computational-statistics, beta-distribution

Most statistical computing packages have functions to sample out of a two-parameter Beta distribution, but not many offer functions for sampling out of a [four-parameter Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Four_parameters). If I want to generate samples $y$ from a four-parameter Beta distribution with lower bound $a$ and upper bound $c$ so that

$$y \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta, c, a)$$

is it sufficient to generate samples $x$ from a two-parameter Beta distribution,

$$x \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$$

and then transform the samples using

$$y = x(c-a) + a$$

or is there some subtlety to the sampling algorithm that I'm not seeing which would result in the samples $y$ not having the desired Beta distribution?

Comment: As the reference says, these parameters merely "alter the scale and location." It's the equivalent of changing the units of measurement.  Because that's routine and easy, there's no need to write special code to offer it.  But you can readily check: why not generate some values and plot their distribution to verify it's what you want?

Comment: @whuber Yes, I have generated some values as you suggested and they look as expected, but I find it is usually misleading to rely only on visual checks of distributions. The calculus for the change-of-variables works out as well analytically, but I just wanted to double check and make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious.

Comment: I agree with the misleading part, so when in doubt, employ qq plots and, if you like, formal distribution tests.  But in this instance if you're getting anywhere near close to what you expect for a decent range of parameters it would be extremely unlikely that you are misunderstanding the documentation.